# formatting annotation for one point from the group

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, seaborn

I'm trying to rotate one of the annotation arrows independently of others. How can I access it separately? Here is the code:

```
for label, x, y in zip(rets.columns, rets.mean(), rets.std()):
    plt.annotate(
        label, 
        xy = (x, y), xytext = (180, 60),
        textcoords = 'offset pixels', ha = 'left', va = 'center',
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = 'fancy', connectionstyle = 'angle3, angleA=0,angleB=90 '))
```

And here the chart, so essentially I want to rotate MSFT annotation (something to do with connectionstyle right?)  few degrees down, and maybe make Google one to be the  on the opposite side
[image: charts] :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `xytext` for that point.
For example:

```
x = np.random.randint(10, size=(5))
y = np.random.randint(10, size=(5))

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlim(-13, 25)
plt.ylim(-1, 15)
for label, i, j in zip(labels, x, y):
    if label=='a' or label=='c':
        plt.annotate(label, xy = (i, j), xytext = (-180, 60),
        textcoords = 'offset pixels', ha = 'left', va = 'center',
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = 'fancy', connectionstyle = 'angle3, angleA=0,angleB=90 '))

    else:
        plt.annotate(label, xy = (i, j), xytext = (180, 60),
        textcoords = 'offset pixels', ha = 'left', va = 'center',
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = 'fancy', connectionstyle = 'angle3, angleA=0,angleB=90 '))
```

[image]

You can play with the parameter until you find what you like!

**EDIT:**

The style is different because I don't use `seaborn`. Repeating the same, but before importing it gives us:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

[image: rotate_seaborn]

Rather more similar, no?

Comment: Thanks, that helped, however I'm wondering why the connections look different from mines. The color is different and it has visible gradient, but I dont see that you change anything in the code concerning connectionstyle

Comment: @AlexT don't have a gradient the arrows. Only the black border is very thick, and it deceives the eye at the tip of the arrow.